# Pass a command line argument to a WInAPI function using assembly language

Tags: masm, masm32

I am learning assembly language using the MASM32 package.

I am stuck with a problem that I am unable to resolve.

I have a small program that accepts a single command line parameter and passes that to a a WInAPI function named OutputDebugStringA which accepts a string as its input parameter.

The problem is that I don't know how to convert the contents of the buffer to a string so that I can pass it to the OutputDebugStringA function

Thanks in advance for any tips

Mathew

**Code**

---

```
.486
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
include \masm32\vkdebug\dbproc\debug.inc
includelib \masm32\vkdebug\dbproc\debug.lib
include \masm32\MasmBasic\MasmBasic.inc



.data
buffer BYTE 128 (5)

.code
start:







 invoke GetCL, 1, addr buffer ; capture first command line parameter, store it on MyBuffer
invoke OutputDebugStringA,Str$(buffer)

invoke ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

---

Comment: Why do you think the buffer needs any sort of conversion? Seems to me like it's already a zero-terminated string.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: Passing the value directly to the function results in the display of the ASCII value of the first character of the passed argument

Comment: You removed the `Str$`, right? Because it makes no sense in this context. What you want to pass to `OutputDebugStringA` is `ADDR buffer`.

Comment: Also, your declaration of `buffer` looks incorrect. What `BYTE 128 (5)` does is reserve space for _a single byte_ with the initial value of 133 (i.e. 128 + 5).

Comment: Changed the line

Comment: invoke OutputDebugStringA,Str$(buffer)

Comment: to 
invoke OutputDebugStringA,addr buffer

Comment: Thanks a lot
Thanks a lot